# Linq expression to filter formcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a FormCollection and I just want to only iterate through the keys the do not contain the string pricing.

So what I tried was this...

```
foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys.Where(k => !k.Contains("Pricing"))){ ... }
```

The problem is the return is not a filtered list its returning boolean values... in which in need the filtered list of string...

AllKeys returns a string[] so in a sense I am just trying to filter a string[] here...

What I am missing here...

Thanks much!

Comment: That looks fine to me - not sure why you would get a bunch of boolean values.  Have you tried inspecting var to see what type it is?

Comment: @JustLoren, the `key` variable declared in the `foreach` loop is of type `string` because the `Where` extension method returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, so you are correct pointing out that it is impossible to get boolean values from this code.

Comment: @gmcalab, `string.Contains(string)` method is case sensitive. Could this be the problem?

Comment: With the above syntax var is a bool. Therefore, its not return an IEnumerable<string> and key is not a string now its a bool. If your saying that it should return the strings with the above syntax than VS2008 is performing some wacky magic here. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the answer...

```
foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys.Where(k => !k.Contains("Pricing")).ToArray<string>()){ ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you're using `Where` and not `Select`?

Using `Where` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` which is what you're expecting.

Using `Select` will return an `IEnumerable<bool>` which is what you say is actually happening.

Comment: Where does not Return the IEnumerable<string>

I tried this...

string[] list = collection.Where(o => !o.Contains("Pricing"));

And it doesn't compile saying the return type is a bool.... I have figured out that answer and posted it.

Comment: @gmcalab: If `collection` is a `FormCollection`/`NameValueCollection` then your `Where` clause will definitely return `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: +1 @Luke, Where will indeed return IEnumerable<string>

foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => !k.Contains("Pricing"))){}

IEnumerable<string> collection = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => !k.Contains("Pricing"));

Both compile perfectly.

Comment: @Luke: Well, I thought it would return an IEnumerable<string> too, but it doesn't. It will not compile with the above syntax it says it returns a bool. It only worked when I added the .ToArray<string>()

Comment: @gmcalab: But you can only call `ToArray<string>` on an `IEnumerable<string>`. The return type of the `Where` call *must* be `IEnumerable<string>` or your `ToArray` call wouldn't compile either.