# How do I ignore some items in a formcolletion? (using mvc 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a list of questions and their input (answers) displayed in a mvc 3 form. I later added in a partial view for comments. But, its adding a comment field. How do ignore comment fields (there is a add comment controller) from my formcollection:

controller code:

```
foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
                {
                    var answer = formCollection[key];
                    int questionId = Convert.ToInt32(key);
                    .......
                }
```

comments:

```
@Html.TextArea("Comment", new { rows = 5, cols = 50 })
```

Comment: Do not include it in the fieldset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688794/linq-expression-to-filter-formcollection) explains how to Filter the FormCollection using a Linq expression which I think is exactly what you wish to do.

Hope that helps.