# How to filter the Application.OpenForms collection with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use `Where` to filter the `Application.OpenForms` collection with Linq, and several questions on this site  [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688794/linq-expression-to-filter-formcollection) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831606/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-from-a-formcollection) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893147/slicing-a-formcollection-by-keys-that-start-with-a-certain-string) suggest that all I that need in order to do that is access its `AllKeys` property. However, even when I create a new Windows Forms application, the collection doesn't seem to have this property at all and doesn't compile when I try to use it. What could be the reason?

Comment: `Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x=> ... );`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to cast it since [`FormCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't implement  `IEnumerable<T>` but only `IEnumerable`:

```
var query = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>()
    .Where(form => ...);
```

However, the `Form` has no `AllKeys` property. Are you confusing webforms and winforms?  In the former there is no `Application.OpenForms`.

Comment: It could be that I confused the two. Either way, the code that you provided is exactly what I needed!