# How do I get each value from each table row in an MVC project?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have the following webgrid in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertSensorsInExistingPredefineView", "PredefinedViews", FormMethod.Post))
{

@gridSensorChoose.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid3-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid3-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid3-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid3-alternating-row",//
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid3-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid3-row-style",//
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:

    gridSensorChoose.Columns(

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorID", format: @<text>  <input readonly="readonly" name="SensorID" id="SensorID" value="@item.SensorID" />  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("DeviceID", format: @<text>  <span id="DeviceID">@item.DeviceID</span>  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorType", format: @<text>  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">@item.SensorType</span>  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorName", @Html.Localize("sensorName").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span><label id="SensorName">@item.SensorName</label> </span>  </text>, style: "col2Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("VAL", format: @<text><span class="Val"> @Html.CheckBox("val") </span></text>, style:"col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("MIN", format: @<text><span class="Min"> @Html.CheckBox("min") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("AVG", format: @<text> <span class="Avg"> @Html.CheckBox("avg") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("MAX", format: @<text> <span class="Max"> @Html.CheckBox("max") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SUM", format: @<text> <span class="Sum"> @Html.CheckBox("sum") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("INT", format: @<text> <span class="Int"> @Html.CheckBox("int") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false)

                                ))


<input type="submit" value="@Html.Localize("save")" formaction="/PredefinedViews/InsertSensorsInExistingPredefineView" />
}
```

This view displays the following html in the browser like so:

```
<table class="webgrid3-table">
<thead>
    <tr class="webgrid3-header">
        <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?   selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorID&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorID</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=DeviceID&amp;sortdir=ASC">DeviceID</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorType&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorType</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Sensor Name
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            VAL
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            MIN
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            AVG
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            MAX
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            SUM
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            INT
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">10</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">2</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 15cm</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">3</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 30cm</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">4</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">101</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness prvi</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">5</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">201</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Ait temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">6</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">202</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Air humidity </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">7</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">203</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Wind speed </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">8</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">204</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Wind direction </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">9</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">205</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Precipitation </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">10</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">206</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Solar radiation </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">51</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">20</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Battery </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">56</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">101</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness drugi</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I now I want to get each value (even if it is false) of each check box (there are six check boxes in total) of each row (that can be any number from zero to whatever depending on how many SensorID(which is unique) there are in DeviceID (which is the same in each row)). But I don't know how to iterate through each row. I treid using FormCollection, but that didnt work out for me, does anyone have any other suggestions that might help me?

```
public ActionResult InsertSensorsInExistingPredefineView(FormCollection sensorCollection)
    {

        foreach (var row in sensorCollection.AllKeys)

            bool _val = sensorCollection["val"] != "false";
            bool _min = sensorCollection["min"] != "false";
            bool _avg = sensorCollection["avg"] != "false";
            bool _max = sensorCollection["max"] != "false";
            bool _sum = sensorCollection["sum"] != "false";
            bool _int = sensorCollection["int"] != "false";

            if (//some logic checking for at least one true value)
            {
               //save to some db table acording to sensorID....
            }

        }
        return view;
    }
```

*I did the whole != "false" thing because the check boxes return values as strings, like strings in the form of "true,false" if it is checked and "false" if it is not checked.*
There must be something I'm doing wrong here, I just edited my first row (SensorID), thinking it can server as a counter but I'm still struggling.

I dont know what to do any more here, is there there a chance I can complete my task using Javascript/jQuery and then send the results to the controller?

I just tried this to see if it will iterate through each row and pick up the values:

```
    <input type="submit" class="DoSomething" value="Do it" />
foreach (WebGridRow row in gridSensorChoose.Rows)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".DoSomething").on("click", function () {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var sensorID = tr.find(".SensorID").html();
            var _val = tr.find(".Val").html();
            var _min = tr.find(".Min").html();
            var _avg = tr.find(".Avg").html();
            var _max = tr.find(".Max").html();
            var _sum = tr.find(".Sum").html();
            var _int = tr.find(".Int").html();
            })
            if (_val == true || _min =! true || _avg == true || _max == true || _sum == true || _int == true ||){
                //ajax send all vars to controller
                }
            //and now iterate through next row

        })
    </script>
```

Maybe I can write out something like that in java script and send it to the controller each time it ends an iteration? And then it starts a new one until there are no more rows.

Comment: You could use LINQ to select the FormCollection values that you're interested in - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688794/linq-expression-to-filter-formcollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688794/linq-expression-to-filter-formcollection)

Comment: But I want all of them, I dont want to filter anything, I just need it to iterate the correct number of times and seperate each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I came to an answer here, with a little help from roryok who steered me in the right way:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertSensorsInExistingPredefineView(FormCollection sensorCollection)
    {
        int[] sensorIds = sensorCollection["SensorID"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
        List<bool> vals = sensorCollection["val"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToList();
        List<bool> mins = sensorCollection["min"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToList();
        List<bool> avgs = sensorCollection["avg"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToList();
        List<bool> maxs = sensorCollection["max"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToList();
        List<bool> sums = sensorCollection["sum"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToList();
        List<bool> ints = sensorCollection["_int"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToList();

        List<bool> adjustVals = new List<bool>();
        adjustVals.Add(vals[0]);
        adjustVals = RemoveFalseAfterTrue(vals, adjustVals);

        List<bool> adjustMins = new List<bool>();
        adjustMins.Add(mins[0]);
        adjustMins = RemoveFalseAfterTrue(mins, adjustMins);

        List<bool> adjustAvgs = new List<bool>();
        adjustAvgs.Add(avgs[0]);
        adjustAvgs = RemoveFalseAfterTrue(avgs, adjustAvgs);


        List<bool> adjustMaxs = new List<bool>();
        adjustMaxs.Add(maxs[0]);
        adjustMaxs = RemoveFalseAfterTrue(maxs, adjustMaxs);

        List<bool> adjustSums = new List<bool>();
        adjustSums.Add(sums[0]);
        adjustSums = RemoveFalseAfterTrue(sums, adjustSums);

        List<bool> adjustInts = new List<bool>();
        adjustInts.Add(ints[0]);
        adjustInts = RemoveFalseAfterTrue(ints, adjustInts);

        for (int i = 0; i < sensorIds.Count(); i++)
        {
            bool val = adjustVals[i];
            bool min = adjustMins[i];
            bool avg = adjustAvgs[i];
            bool max = adjustMaxs[i];
            bool sum = adjustSums[i];
            bool _int = adjustInts[i];
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static List<bool> RemoveFalseAfterTrue(List<bool> initialCheckboxValues, List<bool> adjustedInitialCheckboxValues)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < initialCheckboxValues.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (initialCheckboxValues[i - 1] == false)
            {
                adjustedInitialCheckboxValues.Add(initialCheckboxValues[i]);
            }
        }

        return adjustedInitialCheckboxValues;
    }
```

So after I get the initial values, I had to put them in a list and then remove each false after each true (with a method I created), and now I have my wanted results.

Answer (score 1):

By your line of code, I see you've misunderstood something

```
foreach (var row in sensorCollection.AllKeys) 
{

}
```

The values in sensorCollection are not rows. They are the fields passed from the view.

Your HTML has lots of inputs with the same name. To take one as an example:

```
<input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

`sensorCollection.AllKeys` will contain multiple entries for "val" - one for each row on the grid. You're iterating over each value, then ignoring the value and retrieving the value again. In essence this

```
foreach (var row in sensorCollection.AllKeys)
{
    bool _val = sensorCollection["val"] != "false";
    bool _min = sensorCollection["min"] != "false";
    bool _avg = sensorCollection["avg"] != "false";
    bool _max = sensorCollection["max"] != "false";
    bool _sum = sensorCollection["sum"] != "false";
    bool _int = sensorCollection["int"] != "false";
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
{
    bool _val = sensorCollection["val"] != "false";
    bool _min = sensorCollection["min"] != "false";
    bool _avg = sensorCollection["avg"] != "false";
    bool _max = sensorCollection["max"] != "false";
    bool _sum = sensorCollection["sum"] != "false";
    bool _int = sensorCollection["int"] != "false";
}
```

See how `i` is irrelevant there? So is `row`. You're not referring to it, so these values will always be the same - probably the values for the first row on the grid.

You need to do something like this instead

```
// find the number of values for "val" in the collection
// build a for loop that iterates over the collection
for(int i = 0; i < sensorCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k == "val").Count(); i++)
{
    // get the nth of each key, where n is the instance of "val"  
    bool _val = sensorCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k == "val")[i] != "false";
    // handle the other values (I'm too lazy to type them out)
    // save out the data
}
```

## UPDATE

OK, so I built a new MVC app and replicated your grid and postback, and here's what I found.

Firstly, there are 6 values in sensorCollection.AllKeys - one for each column (val,min,avg,max,sum,int)

Secondly, the data for some reason is encoded as a concatenated string. So if you tick the first val checkbox then `sensorCollection[0] = "true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false"`

I wasn't expecting this, it's a little odd, but we'll work with it. This code should sort you out:

```
public ActionResult InsertSensorsInExistingPredefineView(FormCollection sensorCollection)
{
    bool[] vals = sensorCollection["val"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToArray();
    bool[] mins = sensorCollection["min"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToArray();
    bool[] avgs = sensorCollection["avg"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToArray();
    bool[] maxs = sensorCollection["max"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToArray();
    bool[] sums = sensorCollection["sum"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToArray();
    bool[] ints = sensorCollection["int"].Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Count(); i++)
    {
        // your first row, "Soil Temperature":
        bool val = vals[i];
        bool min = mins[i];
        // etc
    }

}
```

Comment: That makes more sense, but I get the following error: Error 4 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Comment: Ah right, that just means you have to change your collection to something that can. Try `sensorCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k == "val").ElementAt(i)` or `sensorCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k == "val").ToList()[i]`, or failing that `sensorCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k == "val").ToArray()[i]`

Comment: So this should iterate for the val, and any other checkbox I put in the loop, by the number of times of how many rows there are?
Because I put a random thing for it do do inside at it only iterates once if anything or all is checked and doesnt iterate at all if nothing is checked. I need it to iterate so that I can record even the checkboxes give false values.

Comment: I just tested this, it iterates only once if anything is selected and doesnt iterate if nothing is selcected at all. Also when I try adding sensorCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k == "val").ElementAt(i) to watch it says "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions"

Comment: Ignore the previous comments i just deleted, I was messing with the html code there (i changed the action helpers for checkbox to input type checkbox). So now I have the true and false values, but the messed up thing is when I have all val for example ticked I get the bool array filled with 24 instead of 12 values, because as you yourself noticed it types out "true,false" for true.